# How to show percentiles in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, symbology, classification

I have a polygon layer with several fields, like: population, wage, age, etc.

I would like to show the percentile value for those fields.

How can I do that in an automatic way with QGIS 2.6.1?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the pie chart styling,

for more info look at the docs [here](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_diagram_overlay.html)